# vue - axios call not working(Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am beginner on Vue.js.

I am trying to do axios call on my `/src/component/data.js`

The file look like below:

```
const myData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(data());
  });
};

const data = () => {
  return [
    {
      name: "A"
    },
    {
      name: "B"
    }
  ];
};

export { myData };
```

When I am trying to access the data on `HelloWorld.vue`:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { mydata } from "./data";

export default {
...
  async mounted() {
    const response = await axios.get(mydata);
    console.log(response);
  }
};
</script>
```

The error shows

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
```

The result I want is

```
[
    {
      name: "A"
    },
    {
      name: "B"
    }
  ]
```

CodeSandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-haibt-1bnib?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:1790-2040

How to solve it without modifying `data.js`?

Answer (score 1):

there is a typo in your code. you are exporting

```js
export { myData };
```

but, importing

```js
import { mydata } from "./data";
```

but it still doesn't make sense asking data without an endpoint from axios

Comment: If i do not want to modify data.js, how can I get the data in HelloWorld.vue

Comment: i am not asking you to modify data.js I am telling you to correct your import statement in HelloWorld.vue
and it will fix the error but won't accomplish what you trying to do. you can use simple data export rather than using Axios. or should use some sort of Axios moke API

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, Axios is a Javascript library used to make HTTP requests from node.js or XMLHttpRequests from the browser that also supports the ES6 Promise API. So you should have url to your backend API to call axios and get data from there , in your code `Pconst myData = () => {`
  `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`
    `resolve(data());`
  `});`
`};` data function represent just array without any server request, in your case just remove axios.get . Best regards

Comment: If i do not want to modify data.js, how can I get the data in HelloWorld.vue

Comment: instead axios.get(mydata) write mydata

Comment: But it’s promise

Comment: I tried to change it to `const response = mydata;`, it shows undefined in Console

Comment: const response = await mydata;